# Play audio when power button is pressed

Tags: android, audio

I have this snippet code written in my app

Receiver.java

```
if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) && am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
{
    if(u!=null) {
        stopPlaying();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, u);
        mp.start();
    }
}
else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) && am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
{
    if(u2!=null) {
        stopPlaying();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, u2);
        mp.start();
    }
}
}

private void stopPlaying() {
if (mp != null) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}
}
```

It's working perfect, but I noticed that there's a delay in playing the audio when screen is off. I think this is because the device dim the screen before initiating into off state.

I want it to play the off audio when an action that triggers the off state is clicked (like clicking the power button, gestures or double tap to wake and sleep). In this case, I want it to play when the power button is triggered.

Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: you have to check that if your screen light is on or off. when you detect that then there must be a receiver which will tell you is the screen on or of and then you can play your audio. or do what ever you want.

Comment: Can you show me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You add this code.

First you need to add the following permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
```

To handle short and long presses add the following overrides to your activity class:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // Do something here...
        event.startTracking(); // Needed to track long presses
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // Do something here...
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

For BroadcastReceiver

In menifest File

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In MyReceiver.java

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.v("onReceive", "Power button is pressed.");

    Toast.makeText(context, "power button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    // perform what you want here

}
```

Comment: Can I define this method in BroadcastReceiver?  Because my receiver will still play the audio even after the app is terminated.

Comment: I tried changing action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) into .action.equals(ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh, from what I read, the receiver that you gave me is for charging/uncharging your device. What I want to do is, when user press the lock or unlock button, an audio will play.